# iOS bluetooth low energy not detecting peripherals

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

My app won't detect peripherals. Im using light blue to simulate a bluetooth low energy peripheral and my app just won't sense it. I even installed light blue on two devices to make sure it was generating a peripheral signal properly and it is. Any suggestions? My labels are updating and the NSLog is showing that the scanning is starting.

Thanks in advance.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

        #import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>







        @interface ViewController : UIViewController

        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *navDestination;




        @end



        #import "ViewController.h"





        @implementation ViewController

        - (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {


        }

        - (IBAction)navDestination:(id)sender {

            NSString *destinationText  = self.navDestination.text;

         }


        - (void)viewDidLoad {

        }



         - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

             [super viewWillDisappear:animated];



        }



        - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

            [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

        }
        @end



        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        #import "ViewController.h"
        @interface BlueToothViewController : UIViewController

        @property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager *centralManager;

        @property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral *discoveredPerepheral;

        @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *data;

        @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textview;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *charLabel;

        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *isConnected;

        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myPeripherals;

        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *aLabel;



        - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central;

        - (void)centralManger:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:     (CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI;

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error;

-(void)cleanup;

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral;



-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error;

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error;

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error;

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error;

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error;





@end




@interface BlueToothViewController ()

@end

@implementation BlueToothViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];

    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];



}



- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [_centralManager stopScan];

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {

    //you should test all scenarios

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {

        self.aLabel.text = @"I dont do anything because my state is unknown.";

        return;

    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {

        //scan for devices

        [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];

        NSLog(@"Scanning Started");

    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStateResetting) {

        self.aLabel.text = @"I dont do anything because my state is resetting.";

        return;

    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {

        self.aLabel.text = @"I dont do anything because my state is unsupported.";

        return;

    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {

        self.aLabel.text = @"I dont do anything because my state is unauthorized.";

        return;

    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {

        self.aLabel.text = @"I dont do anything because my state is powered off.";

        return;

    }









}

- (void)centralManger:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {



    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);

    self.myPeripherals.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",peripheral.name, RSSI];

    if (_discoveredPerepheral != peripheral) {

        //save a copy of the peripheral

        _discoveredPerepheral = peripheral;

        //and connect

        NSLog(@"Connecting to peripheral %@", peripheral);

        [_centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];

        self.aLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", peripheral];

    }

}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {



    NSLog(@"Failed to connect");

    [self cleanup];

}

-(void)cleanup {

    //see if we are subscribed to a characteristic on the peripheral

    if (_discoveredPerepheral.services != nil) {

        for (CBService *service in _discoveredPerepheral.services) {

            if (service.characteristics != nil) {

                for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

                    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"508EFF8E-F541-57EF-BD82-B0B4EC504CA9"]]) {

                        if (characteristic.isNotifying) {

                            [_discoveredPerepheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:characteristic];

                            return;

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:_discoveredPerepheral];

}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {

    NSLog(@"Connected");



    [_centralManager stopScan];

    NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");



    self.isConnected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected"];



    [_data setLength:0];



    peripheral.delegate = self;



    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];

}

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {

    if (error) { [self cleanup];

        return;

    }

    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {

        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];

    }

    //discover other characteristics

}

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) { [self cleanup];

    return;

}

    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {



            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];



    }

}

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {



    if (error) { NSLog(@"Error");

        return;

    }

    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    self.charLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringFromData];

    //Have we got everything we need?



    if ([stringFromData isEqualToString:@"EOM"]) {

        [_textview setText:[[NSString alloc]initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



        [peripheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:characteristic];



        [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];



    }





}

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {



    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:nil]) {

        return;

    }

    if (characteristic.isNotifying) {

        NSLog(@"Notification began on %@", characteristic);

    }

    else {

        [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];

    }

}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {

    _discoveredPerepheral = nil;



    self.isConnected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connecting..."];



    [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES}];



}



@end
```

Comment: It is obvious! You should add a little more empty lines and everything will work.

Comment: Oh gosh! I didn't realize that would...Wait a minute!!! You little stinker!!! Ha-ha!!! I actually thought you were serious for a second!!! Geez. Now I feel so silly!!!

Comment: CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : Try with it at FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you aren't declaring that you implement the CBCentralManagerDelegate protocol.  Change your BlueToothViewController interface to add the CBCentralManagerDelegate.

```
@interface BlueToothViewController () <CBCentralManagerDelegate>
```